# while loop under fetch() prints the first row only

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

```
if (isset($_GET['srId'])) {
    $srId = $_GET['srId'];
}

$getShowroomDetails = $db->prepare('SELECT
a.id, a.roomName, a.roomImage, a.roomDetails,
b.id, b.showroom, b.activityName, b.activityPlace, b.activityDate,b.activityDetails,b.activityImage
FROM movies_showroom AS a
INNER JOIN movies_showroom_details AS b ON (a.id = b.showroom)
WHERE a.id=?
');
$getShowroomDetails->bind_param('i', $srId);

if ($getShowroomDetails->execute()) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($getShowroomDetails, $id, $roomName, $roomImage, $roomDetails, $showroom, $sid, $activityName, $activityPlace, $activityDate, $activityDetails, $activityImage);
    $getShowroomDetails->fetch();
}
    ?>
```

Now printing some vars in the `HTML`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right">
         <img src="../images/showRooms/<?php print $roomImage ?>" width="256"
         height="256" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"/>
   </div>

         <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 pull-right">
              <div class="pull-right">
                   <h4 class="text-bold">نبذه عن القاعة</h4>
                       <?php print $roomDetails ?>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now comes the while loop

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($getShowroomDetails)) {
   printf("%s %s\n", $activityName, $activityPlace);
}
```

here is `while loop` read the first row only?

Comment: No while loop give you all possible results of your query check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: Grate, so why it just fetching one row under the loop?

Comment: Show us how you use your whlie loop

Comment: it's like it posted in my question, see if I removed the upper `$getShowroomDetails->fetch();` the `while loop` works fine but of course the other three vars will not show `$roomName`,  `$roomDetails`, ...

Comment: If you want to fetch more than one row, wouldn't 'mysqli_fetch_assoc' work?

Comment: If anything that loop should be ***skipping*** the first row...?! Does that loop literally come *after* all the other stuff you show? This question is pretty confusing and unclear.

Comment: @deceze I write all my code very clear I think so!! and yes the `while loop` comes after here is a link to all my file on aDrive 'https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B6ED478A72FB6A78!32729&authkey=!AAetF-HV_d1nl2M&ithint=file%2cphp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to print all the records you can use mysqli_fetch_array:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Associative array
```

Do the following changes in your code :

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getShowroomDetails,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       print_r($row); // it gives all the records
      // printf("%s %s\n", $activityName, $activityPlace); // I don't know why you have used it, that's why I've commented this line
    }
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

Comment: its because your query should be assigned to a variable like :
`$query='your query'; $getShowroomDetails=mysqli_query($con,$query);` where $con is connection object

Answer (score 0):

If I get the problem right, you are looking for mysqli_fetch_all()

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php for further details.

Be aware of your memory. If you assume a huge result, the better (lower memory impact) way is to handle it in the loop in the template. This may be a bit different in your case, depends on your setup :)

```
<div>
    <h4 class="text-bold">نبذه عن القاعة</h4>
    <?php 
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($getShowroomDetails)) {
            printf("%s %s\n", $activityName, $activityPlace);
        }
        print $roomDetails ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I can't understand what did you say in your answer? pls give a clear example what u just write I did it but still not working

Comment: Somehow I miss read your question, sorry. - If you just want the first element you can do: 
    $roomDetail = mysqli_stmt_fetch($getShowroomDetails);

with out the while